# list style image in tcpdf

Tags: php, tcpdf

How can I set list-style-image property to list in tcpdf? Below is my code

```
<style>
  .content{
    color: #111;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:normal;
  }
  .title{
    color: #3e3e3e;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
  }
  ol,ul{
    list-style-image: url('images/leaf_icon.jpg');
  }
</style>
```

`title and content divs` get the css but not in `ol,ul`

Any idea how to achieve that ?

Answer (score 2):

I found this for set list-style-image property to list in tcpdf :

```
<style>
    ul{
        list-style-type:img|jpg|1|1|path/to/file/li_puce.jpg;
    }
</style>
```

type|image_type|size_x|size_y|path_file

Sorry for my english

Comment: It's a great solution.